# Polynomial regression giving wrong answer using Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I've got a set of toy data that has the form :

```
x - x**2 + x**3
```

I'm trying to create a Python script that uses Tensorflow to predict the weights, which in this case should be [1, -1, 1].  However, when I run it, I come up with ridiculous answers.

This is my code:

```
# Optional; supresses warnings about GPU
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Read the data
COLUMNS = ["url", "title_length", "article_length", "keywords", "shares"]
data = np.genfromtxt("OnlineNewsPopularityNonLinear.csv", delimiter=',', names=COLUMNS)

# Determine how many data points we're using and the order of the equation
number_of_records = data.size
equation_order = 3

# Set up the variables for weights and bias, but as matrices
w = tf.Variable(np.zeros([equation_order, 1]), dtype="float32", name="w")
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros([1]), dtype="float32", name="b")

content_info_temp = np.zeros([number_of_records, equation_order])
content_info = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[number_of_records, equation_order])
actual_shares = tf.placeholder("float32")

# Input data should be a matrix of [number_of_records, equation_order] where
# each value has been raised to the appropriate power, according to
# our model.  We'll need to call it 
for i in range(equation_order):
  print (i)
  content_info_temp[:, i] = np.power(data["article_length"], (i+1))/np.max(np.power(data["article_length"], (i+1)))

# Create the prediction; it's still y = mx + b, but in this case
# m is a matrix of weights, and x is a matrix of values
predicted_shares = tf.add(tf.matmul(content_info, w), b)

# Loss is the same as before.
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(predicted_shares - actual_shares))

# Create the optimizer
step_size = .001
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(step_size).minimize(error)

# Create the model
model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Create the session to run the algorith
with tf.Session() as session:

   # Initialize everything
   session.run(model)

   # Run the algorithm
   for i in range(100000):
      #Just as before, we run the algorithm, but we're feeding in normalized matrixes rather than single values
      #session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={content_info: input_data, actual_shares: data['shares']/np.max(data["shares"])})
      session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={content_info: content_info_temp, actual_shares: data['shares']/np.max(data['shares'])})
      # Display every 100 results
      if (i % 100 == 0):
         print (session.run(w))
         #print (session.run(predicted_shares - actual_shares))

   #Display the final result    
   w_value = session.run(w)

   print ("FINAL:")
   print (w_value)

   print (w_value[0]*np.max(data["article_length"]))
   print (w_value[1]*np.max(session.run(tf.pow(data["article_length"], 2))))
   print (w_value[2]*np.max(session.run(tf.pow(data["article_length"], 3))))
```

If I run this, I get:

Before de-normalizing:

```
[[ 0.14678337]
 [ 0.01708614]
 [-0.01448759]]
```

After de-normalizing:

```
[ 141.49916077]
[ 15878.08398438]
[-12978583.]
```

In case it matters (I assume it doesn't) I'm using Tensorflow 1.2.

Any ideas?  Thanks...

[MAJOR EDIT:

OK, based on comments, I've revamped the code to look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Read the data
COLUMNS = ["url", "title_length", "article_length", "keywords", "shares", "shares2"]
data = np.genfromtxt("OnlineNewsPopularityNonLinear.csv", delimiter=',', names=COLUMNS)

x_raw = data["article_length"]

x_data = np.zeros([3, 100])
x_data[0] = x_raw/np.max(x_raw)
x_data[1] = x_raw**2/np.max(x_raw**2)
x_data[2] = x_raw**3/np.max(x_raw**3)

print(x_data)

w_set = np.zeros([1, 3])
w_set[0] = np.array([1, -1, 1])

print(w_set)

#y_data = np.matmul(w_set, x_data)
y_data = np.zeros([1, 100])
y_data[0] = data["shares"]/np.max(data["shares"])

print(y_data)

w = tf.Variable(np.zeros([1, 3]), dtype="float32", name="w")
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros([1]), dtype="float32", name="b")

X = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[3, 100])
Y = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[1, 100])

Ypred = tf.add(tf.matmul(w, X), b)

error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Ypred, Y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.01).minimize(error)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Create the session to run the algorith
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)

    # Run the algorithm
    for i in range(5000000):
        _, loss, Wcur = session.run([optimizer, error, w], feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})
        if (i % 10000 == 0):
           print (loss, Wcur)
```

When I artificially make the data follow the appropriate weights of (1, -1, 1), it works fine.  When I use the "real" data (which you can find here: http://www.nicholaschase.com/OnlineNewsPopularityNonLinear.csv) it seems to level out with

```
2.67402e-10 [[-0.00169705  0.00216109  0.99922621]]
2.67402e-10 [[-0.00169705  0.00216109  0.99922621]]
2.67402e-10 [[-0.00169705  0.00216109  0.99922621]]
2.67402e-10 [[-0.00169705  0.00216109  0.99922621]]
2.67402e-10 [[-0.00169705  0.00216109  0.99922621]]
2.67402e-10 [[-0.00169705  0.00216109  0.99922621]]
2.67402e-10 [[-0.00169705  0.00216109  0.99922621]]
2.67402e-10 [[-0.00169705  0.00216109  0.99922621]]
2.67402e-10 [[-0.00169705  0.00216109  0.99922621]]
2.67402e-10 [[-0.00169705  0.00216109  0.99922621]]
```

The "real" data was created with a spreadsheet, so it should be just accurate, no?

Thanks...]

Comment: If you print the error for each iteration of the gradient descent loop, does the error get smaller or larger?

Comment: Good question; when I try, the line:

    actual_shares = tf.placeholder("float32")

gives me

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float

which makes NO sense.

Comment: Maybe your input data is malformed. You should double-check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Do you mean

```
x[0] - x[1]**2 + x[2]**3
```

Next it is hard to run your code without the data. I would start by a sanity check to test whether your data really follows the given equation. I would guess that this is not the case. Because a real MWE is correct

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

number_of_records = 1000
equation_order = 3

# toy data
X_data = np.random.randn(number_of_records, equation_order)
X_data[1] = X_data[1]**2
X_data[2] = X_data[2]**3
Y_data = np.matmul(X_data, np.array([[1], [-1], [1.]]))

w = tf.Variable(np.zeros([equation_order, 1]), dtype="float32", name="w")
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros([1]), dtype="float32", name="b")

X = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[None, equation_order])
Y = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[None, 1])

Ypred = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w), b)

error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Ypred, Y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.1).minimize(error)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Create the session to run the algorith
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)

    # Run the algorithm
    for _ in range(200):
        _, loss, Wcur = session.run([optimizer, error, w], feed_dict={X: X_data, Y: Y_data})
        print loss, Wcur.transpose()
```

and returns

```
5.33256e-14 [[ 0.99999988 -0.99999988  0.99999988]]
```

I would say this looks suspicious:

```
for i in range(equation_order):
  print (i)
  content_info_temp[:, i] = np.power(data["article_length"], (i+1))/np.max(np.power(data["article_length"], (i+1)))
```